# Trailing slash in Jekyll permalink

Tags: jekyll

I am migrating my website from [https://code4projects.net/](https://code4projects.net) to https://sasadangelo.github.io/code4projects/.

The old website used a URL structure like this:

```
https://<domain>/<base URL>/:slug/
```

Now in my code, I am changing [this line](https://github.com/sasadangelo/code4projects/blob/165549d1d8bcb2ea989bbede540f74857a278ccb/_config.yml#L39) in:

```
permalink: /:slug/
```

adding the trailing slash. It seems it works, but I have a lot of doubts because it's not clear to me the meaning of this section in the `_config.yml` file:

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "authors"
    values:
      layout: "author"
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    values:
      layout: "post"
      permalink: /:slug
  - scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      layout: "default"
```

I tried to [read the docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#global), but the concept of scope is not clear to me.

Moreover, I expected my change only applied to posts (in the _posts folder), but it's not clear to me why it also works for pages (all in the root folders).

Why Jekyll doesn't have a folder _pages for pages? Moreover, in the section above what is the meaning of `defaults` array and the type field?

I tried to search for info but the one found only confused me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Collections vs pages

Jekyll has collections, for which you can define a name, a folder, etc. Posts (and drafts) are also collections but standard Jekyll ones.

Pages are not a collection but the most basic building block for content. They’re useful for standalone content, e.g. an index page or a static about page. Typically, some pages are stored in the root folder. Other pages live in (sub)folders without underscore, e.g. pages or documents.

You can find more information in the content section on the Jekyll docs start page: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/

#### Defaults array

You can read more about [Front Matter Defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/) in the docs, too!

> The defaults key holds an array of scope/values pairs that define what defaults should be set for a particular file path, and optionally, a file type in that path.
>
> ```
>   -
>     scope:
>       path: "" # an empty string here means all files in the project
>       type: "posts" # previously `post` in Jekyll 2.2.
>     values:
>       layout: "default"
> ```

> Now, this will only set the layout for files where the type is posts. The different types that are available to you are pages, posts, drafts or any collection in your site. While type is optional, you must specify a value for path when creating a scope/values pair.

##### Defaults for pages

For pages, you have fewer options, see https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#pages

Your page index is also a page. If you set an option for pages, you need to overwrite the permalink in the index file of your site.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried to add something similar to posts for pages but Jekyll isn't able to render it. For example, suppose you want to put all pages in the _pages folder and define a global permalink for them (something like permalink: /:slug/), how I can do it? I tried to do something similar to posts but it doesn't work. Can you help me on this?

Comment: The options for permalinks for pages are limited, and the index could be a problem as well. See my update above. Pretty difficult to deal with the different paths though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and comments. To be honest the scope and type concepts are It's still not clear to me. At this point, I think it's better I do some tests on my own to try to figure out what I am looking for. I will use your inputs for this. If I find an answer to my problems I will update this thread. Thank you again.